# Missing subject

Tags: passive-voice

In the middle of the necklace, there are placed two sensors.

I don't think this is a correct sentence. How should I rewrite this, keeping its passivity?

Comment: It's okay I think: the subject is 'there'. The preposition phrase 'in the middle of the necklace' is an adjunct of place, and 'there are placed two sensors' is the main clause.

Comment: @BillJ What's the role of *two sensors*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence could be further trimmed to 'In the middle of the necklace are placed two sensors.' Doing so preserves your wish to retain the passive and, to my mind, makes it more elegant. No meaning is lost but the slight elevation to elegance makes it a better sentence.